Is it possible to share a CC-BY-licensed article on ResearchGate that contains copyrighted material?
My open-access Elsevier article (CC-BY 4.0) contains a third-party figure (from a Springer subscription book). I obtained permission and the caption correctly states that the copyright of the figure is owned by Springer (which means that the figure itself is excluded from the CC-BY license). Do I understand correctly that I cannot publicly share the article on ResearchGate because of the figure and that I would need extra permission to do so?

What does your agreement with Springer say, exactly?

First, IANAL, but my common sense evaluation is that you can share the article as you please since you have Springer's permission. But others can't share that image even though it is in your article.
I've assumed that Springer is aware that your paper has a CC-BY license. It would be more complicated if you hid that from them. But you have explicit permission apparently. And such permission means nothing if you are forbidden from sharing your work. I would still need to observe Springer's copyright if I want to take from your paper, however. Nor is it likely that you could use that figure elsewhere without additional permission.
Of course, I can't promise that Springer will come to the same conclusion and you could seek extra clarification from them.

Maybe it would be even more clear to say "others need permission by Springer for the original figure if they want to share that image alone". IIRC, Springer asks a number of questions during their automated license generation for image re-use. If they don't ask about the license of the future paper before granting the OP the right to reuse the figure that's their decision (and I don't know whether from their perspective a CC-licensed paper is worse than a paper behind the Elsevier paywall?)
